# laravel return to view instead of 500

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

So i am creating a multi roll laravel website.
there you can view posts depending on your role.
for example, a 'partner' can view all posts with the id: 1,2,6
in my controller i have a function that checks if this is true. since you can alter the link
http://localhost:8000/partner/posts{postid}.

now whenever i do
http://localhost:8000/partner/posts{post id that does not exist}.

i get a 500 server error. but how can i just return the user to a specific view instead of this 500 server error

Comment: Maybe u did a typo - `http://localhost:8000/partner/posts{postid}`, forgot the last `/` between posts and the id?

Comment: no it is not a typo. the post that i want to look up is non existing, so i want to return it to a specific page

Comment: can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: @ericmp i get an 500 server error. which is logical because the 'id' of the post does not exist in the database. so i want to return the user to a specific view

Comment: Check if a post with the given `id` exists and show contents if it does, redirect/show a different message if it doesn't

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? It could help to share the code that causes the problem

Comment: @Delanovanlonden it is not logical to get a 500 error when you are trying to access a post that does not exist. The logical error code for that is 404 so you first need to figure out why you are getting a 500 error instead of a 404 and then you can go on to create a custom error page for 404 errors. If you make a custom page for 500 errors with the assumption that it will be shown when a model is missing then all your unhandled errors will also show that page

Comment: @apokryfos if i turn on debugging mode i get this error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
a 500 error since the query got an error. but good to know that all my unhandled errors will indeed show the custom 500 error page

Comment: *Invalid parameter number* is not an error you'd expect to get just because a model does not exist. I would recommend you take a look at [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) which allows Laravel to take care of finding the model for you and also ensures the error you get if the model is not found is a 404 error